# Prerequisites for JSP project

Tags: vb.net, jsp, ide, code-conversion

I have developed a software using vb.net. Now as per the client's requirement I have to develop this project as web application using JSP. I am new for JSP.

First I want to know, is there any way to convert the vb.net code to JSP? Is there any application is available to copy the vb.net code and get equivalent JSP code ?

If no such conversion application available mean then What are the perquisites for developing a web application in JSP? What are the tools or IDES available for that? Suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are no such convertion, but hey.. maybe someone out there can do it, I dont know.

For the IDE you can try Eclipse or Netbean IDE, both of them are free and have the best Intellisence for Java Environtment development.